# Как присвоить значение переменной функции, не входящей в нее

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер. Такой вопрос, как присвоить значения переменных a и b из main'a функции sum. Никак не могу разобраться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код нужно класть в виде кода, а не в виде скриншота. Не первый вопрос уже.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте я вас совсем запутаю, чтобы вам было что почитать.:)

Во-первых, следует стараться писать функции так, чтобы они выполняли одно конкретное действие. Ваша же функция суммирует два числа и выводит их на консоль. Если вам понадобится просто получить сумму двух числе, то вам придется писать еще одну функцию. Это можно было бы избежать, если бы ваша функция только вычисляла сумму двух числе и возвращала ее вызывающему коду.

Другая проблема с вашей функцией состоит в том, что сумма двух чисел типа `int`, может не умещаться в объекте этого типа, то есть может иметь место переполнение. Тогда в этом случае функцию даст неверный результат.

В принципе функция может быть определена двумя способами. Первый способ по числу параметров соответствует вашему объявлению функции. Но это единственное, с чем она схожа с определением функции, показанной мною в следующей демонстрационной программе. Я специально использовал коллизию имен `sum`, чтобы, как я уже сказал, вам было что почитать.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void sum( long long int &sum, int a, int b )
{
    sum = static_cast<long long int>( a ) + b;
}   

int main() 
{
    long long int sum;

    ::sum( sum, std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max() );

    std::cout << "sum of "
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
              <<  " + "
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
              << " is equal to "
              << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль следующий

```
sum of 2147483647 + 2147483647 is equal to 4294967294
```

В языках программирования параметр функции sum, объявленный как `long long int &sum`, то есть объявленный как ссылка, называется выходным параметром. Вместо ссылки можно было бы использовать также указатель в качестве первого параметра.

Второе более простое и естественное объявление функции может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

long long int sum( int a, int b )
{
    return static_cast<long long int>( a ) + b;
}   

int main() 
{
    long long int sum;

    sum = ::sum( std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max() );

    std::cout << "sum of "
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
              <<  " + "
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
              << " is equal to "
              << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь значение в вызывающий код передается через значение возврата из функции.

В обоих случаях для результата используется тип `long long int`, который позволяет избежать переполнения, как это видно из вывода на консоль.

Что касается вашей программы, то имейте в виду, что данное предложение в `main`

```
void sum();
```

является локальным объявлением функции с именем `sum`, которая не имеет параметров и имеет тип возвращающего значения `void`. Это локальное объявление скрывает объявление **другой** функции `sum`, объявленной перед `main`.

Comment: Как-то это все слишком красиво и сложно для подобного вопроса...

Comment: @andy.37 Я так написал, чтобы не повторяться с предыдущем ответом. Чтобы для автора вопроса была новая интересная информация.:)

Comment: Не уверен, что задающему подобный вопрос нужна такая информация (на данном этапе). Тут бы в основах разобраться, например, почему код в вопросе не должен компилироваться. Что такое локальные и глобальные переменные. Впрочем, ответ хорош, +

Comment: Хмм. А почему ты в первом фрагменте кода long long int sum указываешь. Она ведь находится вне функции=> не сработает. Объясни пожалуйста.

Comment: @Men'sPhisique Первая функция имеет три параметра, и ей передается соответственно три аргумента: переменная sum, объявленная в main, причем передается ссылка на нее, и два выражения, которые дают максимальное значение для числа типа int. Так как первый параметр - это ссылка, то изменение его в функции при ведет к изменению переменной, объявленной в main.

Comment: Это снова я. Написал твой первый код. Сначал в выражении после оператора static_cast написал ВСЕ сложение в скобках (a+b)-не сработало. Затем взял в скобки только (a) и все заработало как надо, почему так получилось?
    return static_cast<long long int >(a)+b;

Comment: @Men'sPhisique Когда компилятор вычисляет выражение, он приводит операнды к общему типу, и этот тип становится типом результирующего значения. Когда вы написали static_cast<long long int>( a + b ), то общим типом для выражения a + b является тип int. И произошло переполнение результата. Когда используется выражение  static_cast<long long int>( a ) + b, то левый операнд оператора + имеет тип long long int, и компилятор преобразовал правый операнд к этому типу, то есть к типу с большим рангом. Поэтому переполнения не произошло.

Comment: То есть теперь функция имеет доступ к двум большим ячейкам памяти вместо одной, как в моем ошибочном варианте?

Comment: @Men'sPhisique Правильно будет сказать, что в результате явного преобразования ,одного операнда к типу long long int, оператор + преобразует второй операнд также к этому типу перед выполнением операции.e

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, лучше так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    cout << sum;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    sum(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

В данном случае переменные `a` и `b` в функции `sum` не присваиваются, а передаются в качестве параметров. Переменные `a` и `b` в функции `main` - совсем другие переменные. Когда вы выполняете вызов функции `sum`, значения переменных `a` и `b` копируются в стековый кадр функции `sum`. Далее программа работает только с ними. Заводить параметр функции `sum` нет смысла, поскольку изменения этой переменной внутри функции никак не повлияет на её значение вне функции, так как повторюсь, это уже совсем другая переменная.

Есть второй вариант: сделать возврат значения из функции, а результат выводить в функции `main`. Это будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int s = sum(a, b);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, все получилось. Но почему когда мы убрали sum, все сработало?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: На какие темы информацию почитать, чтоб впредь здесь вопросов не возникало?

Comment: Вопросы всегда будут. Эти вещи всегда разъясняются в начале любого учебника. Внимательно читайте материал, понимайте, выполняйте задания, практикуйтесь. В этом всё программирование.

Comment: И вроде бы в 12й строке вместо sum должно быть написана переменная s, да?

Comment: @Men'sPhisique, да, верно, я опечатался. Harry уже исправил мой ответ.